# How do I start an application as a service?

Tags: 12.04, services, autostart, startup-applications

So I would like a couple of applications to run as services when the machine reboots without the need to login, is this possible?

Applications are:

- Thunderbird Mail
- xChat IRC

This way my email filters will work and I can log the IRC channels I need if my machine restarts and I'm not able to login at the time.

I have them configured to Auto Start when I login nut how can I add them as a service?

Answer (score 1):

Since these are GUI applications, it'd be hard to start them as a "service". The alternative I can think of is:

1. Set them to autostart when you login
2. Set your system to automatically login

Comment: I have #1 but I don't want to auto login +1 for the effort

Answer (score 0):

Try using `xvfb`, which creates a "fake" X display that your GUI program can think its displaying on when no one is logged in in reality.